# Convert months arranged in columns into date variable for Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to write a script that reads the across the array in the column headings for each month and converts it into an attribute that can be read by the datetime module in Python which follows the attribute format (year, month,day):

year        Jan  Feb March   April   May  June July  August  Sept  Oct  Nov  Dec

2001            1;        32;      45;      15;     25;    30;   125;   524;    246;  123;  528;  458

I know that transposing the data and converting the months into numbers may make it easier but I have thousands of data lines I would have to do this with and I am afraid to compromise the data structure with any user error.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What format is the source file? A text file with ";" as a delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want.
Let's say you have a line of data :

```
l = 2001 1; 32; 45; 15; 25; 30; 125; 524; 246; 123; 528; 458
```

then split it :

```
t = l.split()
```

pop the year :

```
YYYY = t.pop(0)

t
['1;', '32;', '45;', '15;', '25;', '30;', '125;', '524;', '246;', '123;', '528;']
```

You can extract the months from that first line, let's build a full year :

```
y = "Jan Feb March April May June July August Sept Oct Nov Dec".split()
```

Suppose you have some incomplete  data where the first line is:

```
d = "Year Jan Feb May June July August Sept Oct Nov Dec".split()
d.pop(0)
```

just build your datetime with :

```
for x in range(len(d)):
     dt = datetime.date(YYYY, y.index(d[x])+1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is very simple and does solve the problem of reading the values in correctly. However, if I have several thousand rows of this data, how can the months be declared as a variable where I can fit them into the standard datetime format:                       
                    data = date(year,month,1)

Comment: I used the x in range(len(t)) to generate the months, the print gives 2001, 1, 1 and so on ... what is what you need to convert to a date -- I just edited the answer, is it better so ?